# Сохранение чекбокса в куки, с последующей проверкой jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, cookie

Помогите доработать код! Я только учусь, не ругайте сильно...

1. есть чекбоксы - id1...id6, а так же value, который может меняться

получаем значения id и value:

```
 var id = this.getAttribute('id');
 var value = this.getAttribute('value');
```

задача проверить чекбоксы, если отметка стоит, сделать выборку - `categoryFilter('other'+ id, value);`, если отметки нет - `categoryFilter('other'+ id,'');`

все работает, но при обновлении страницы выборка сохраняется, а отметки у чекбокса нет, я так понимаю нужно использовать cookie, дальше у меня загвостка... помогите начинающему

я не понимаю в каком виде нужно сохранять данные и как их потом использовать!?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){    
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

 var id = this.getAttribute('id');
 var value = this.getAttribute('value');

 if(id == undefined) return;

 if(this.checked) {
 categoryFilter('other' + id, value);
 } else {   
 categoryFilter('other' + id,'');
 }
});    
});
```

Comment: @Dimastik86, вам не надоело еще? Заплатили бы $10 программисту, он бы давно уже всё вам сделал.

Comment: сделаете за 10 баксов? я согласен!

Comment: @Dimastik86, только сохранение чекбоксов в куку и возврат их обратно? Согласен 8)

Comment: не только )) будет еще несколько пунктов ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var isCheck = false;

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    isCheck = (isset($.cookie("check"+i) && $.cookie("check"+i) != '')?$.cookie("check"+i):false;

    if (isCheck){
        $('#isCheck'+i). attr('checked','checked');
    }else{
        $('#isCheck'+i). removeAttr('checked') ;
    }

}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

    var id = this.attr('id');
    var value = this.val();

    if(id == undefined) return;

    if( this.is(':checked') ) {
         categoryFilter('other' + id, value);
         $.cookie('check' + id, value);
    } else {   
        categoryFilter('other' + id,'');
        $.cookie('check' + id, '');
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Для куков можешь подключить плагин у jQuery:

   [`jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.3`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
2. Чтобы занести значение: `jQuery.cookie('nameCook', 'value');` в имя куков можешь вставить например следующее: `'check'+id` , а в `'value'` саму переменную `value`, т.е. в куках уже будет лежать следующее: `check1=true , check2=false , check3=true` ...
3. При загрузке читаем из куков значения, можно в цикле. И буквально: если существует `check1`, то ставим `checked = check1` ...

   ```
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       isCheck = jQuery.cookie("check"+i); // забираем значение из кук        
   }
   ```

вместо цикла можно просто по id получить значение jQuery.cookie("check"+id);
Вот примерный алгоритм твоего вопроса )